# Take input field data to save in select option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this dropdown list with different values. What i am trying to do is whenever I select other option, the hidden div with id=othertype show and I will type in input field and want to save that data but its not working. I can't use the same name attribute twice I know but I don't want a separate column just for other input. Is it possible to save the input value in same column as options? I want value of input field and not the value I am passing in other option which is other itself.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="p_type">Type*:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="qp_type" id="p_type" required>
        <option  value="Css">CSS</option>
        <option  value="HTML">HTML</option>
        <option  value="PhP">PhP</option>
        <option  value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="otherType" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="pType">If you chose ‘Other’, please describe below:</label>
        <input id="pType" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#p_type').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="Other"){
    $("#otherType").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#otherType").hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using the `value` attribute of the option for anything other than checking if it's "Other"?  You could use the `.text()` for this instead of `.val()` and store the value of `pType` in your option's `value`  (or you could just store it as a `data-` attribute, but ... possibly bad form)

Comment: I think that you should create separate column for this data,  because it's different type, and you should put into DB information that user select option "other". Of course you can put this data into the same DB column but it's not correct IMO.

Comment: I did use the text() but somehow its not working. yeah, I have same approached but can't able to find the example as how to do it.

Comment: @kris_IV You're assuming that by "column" he's referring to a database column.  You could easily be correct, however there's nothing else in the question that validates that assumption.

Comment: Thanks Kris_IV.. yeah, that would be the last option. He got it right, I was talking about db column but when there is already a column, to save and show the result, i think it is'nt a good approach to stuffing the db with additional columns

Comment: @stackkid The `.val()` for a select is taken from the value of the selected option.  The `.text()` of a select is the entire text (from *all* the options).  To get just the text of selected option use `if ($("option:selected", this).text() === "Other")`

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of behaviour, [https://jsfiddle.net/v8ananwr/](https://jsfiddle.net/v8ananwr/)?

Comment: This question is really confusing. The code you have to show the input field, should normally show it. At this point you enter some value in this input, and you want to get the inserted value. `What you what to do with this value?`

Comment: Are you wanting the value in the same column in your db whether it's from the text input or the select input?  Is that your goal?

Comment: Thanks Franco, I just want to select other from dropdown. It will show the hidden div with input field. I want to add the data in it and wanted to save it  in a same column as if i choose any other value from drop down. Like, If I select "CSS", it will send "CSS", but when I select other, other will open an input field to enter the data which isn't present in list.

Comment: Yeah, Rasclatt. It is, because its all part of dropdown. if anyone chooses any of the above options, the value goes through but when it select the other, it will show the hidden div with text field to insert custom option.

Comment: You can create 3rd hidden input and store data to DB  in this input

Comment: Thanks alot Kris_IV, Rasclatt, Franco, and Tibrogargan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use either the input of the text field or the value from the dropdown. You can just enable or disable the one field. The names can be the same, that is not a problem.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="p_type">Type*:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="qp_type" id="p_type" required>
        <option  value="Css" selected>CSS</option>
        <option  value="HTML">HTML</option>
        <option  value="PhP">PhP</option>
        <option  value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="otherType" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="pType">If you chose 'Other', please describe below:</label>
        <!-- START OFF WITH THIS ONE DISABLED, NAME IT THE SAME AS ABOVE --->
        <input id="pType" type="text" name="qp_type" disabled>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=qp_type]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Other') {
            $('#otherType').show();
            $('#pType').prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else {
            $('#otherType').hide();
            $('#pType').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Rasclatt. It worked. Thanks Champ once again.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the value of the selected option to the value from the input field.

```js
function init() {
 $('#p_type').on('change',function(){
  if( $("option:selected", this).text()==="Other"){
  $("#otherType").show()
  }
  else{
  $("#otherType").hide()
  }
 });

 $('#pType').on('change',function(){
  // selector should be '#p_type option[text="Other"]', but it's returning an empty array
  $('#p_type option:selected').val( $(this).val() )
  console.log( $('#p_type').val() );
 } );
}

$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="p_type">Type*:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="qp_type" id="p_type" required>
        <option  value="Css">CSS</option>
        <option  value="HTML">HTML</option>
        <option  value="PhP">PhP</option>
        <option  value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="otherType" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="pType">If you chose ‘Other’, please describe below:</label>
        <input id="pType" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```